# Issue with varadic template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to write a helper template method that takes in the type names for each kind of analysis I want to do. I want the api to look somthing like this:

```
doMultiAnalysis<FrequencyResult, DiffusionResult, GeneralCipherResult>(vector, plainText, cipherText, length, a1Context, (TroyCipher*) &a1, 1000);
```

I created this recursive template that operates on the current template argument and then passes the rest back to the function:

```
template<typename T, typename... rest>
void doMultiAnalysis(std::vector<Result*>& vector, u8* plainText, u8* cipherText, u64 length, TroyContext* context, TroyCipher* cipher, u32 iterations) {
    T* result = new T{};
    result->doAnalysis(plainText, cipherText, length, context, cipher, iterations);
    vector.push_back((Result*) result);
    std::cout << *result << std::endl;
    doMultiAnalysis<rest...>(vector, plainText, cipherText, length, context, cipher, iterations);
}
```

If I try to compile this code with MSVC I of course get "No matching overloaded functions found" because the base case doesn't exist. So If I do this:

```
template<typename T, typename... rest>
void doMultiAnalysis(std::vector<Result*>& vector, u8* plainText, u8* cipherText, u64 length, TroyContext* context, TroyCipher* cipher, u32 iterations) {
    T* result = new T{};
    result->doAnalysis(plainText, cipherText, length, context, cipher, iterations);
    vector.push_back((Result*) result);
    std::cout << *result << std::endl;
    doMultiAnalysis<rest...>(vector, plainText, cipherText, length, context, cipher, iterations);
}

template<typename none = void>
constexpr void doMultiAnalysis(std::vector<Result*>& vector, u8* plainText, u8* cipherText, u64 length, TroyContext* context, TroyCipher* cipher, u32 iterations) {
}
```

The compiler gives "ambiguous call to overloaded function" on the line:

```
doMultiAnalysis<rest...>(vector, plainText, cipherText, length, context, cipher, iterations);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Also I am aware that homemade crypto is a bad idea. This is a personal project for fun that will never be used in production.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of undefined behavior!  `T* result = new T{}; ...   vector.push_back((Result*) result);` is not great.

Comment: Don't use C-style casts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: try with

```
template <int = 0>
constexpr void doMultiAnalysis(std::vector<Result*>& vector, u8* plainText, u8* cipherText, u64 length, TroyContext* context, TroyCipher* cipher, u32 iterations) {
}
```

intstead of

```
template<typename none = void>
constexpr void doMultiAnalysis(std::vector<Result*>& vector, u8* plainText, u8* cipherText, u64 length, TroyContext* context, TroyCipher* cipher, u32 iterations) {
}
```

With your version, calling `doMultiAnalysis()` with the last type, you have an ambiguity because both `doMultianalysis()` match.

With

```
template <int = 0>
constexpr void doMultiAnalysis(...)
```

you have that calling `doMultiAnalysis()` with the last type matches only the variadic version and when this version call `doMultiAnalysis<rest...>()` with empty `rest...` list, matches (only) the `int = 0` version.

Comment: @TroyNeubauer - explanation added (but I suppose it's obvious)